# Creating complex table using CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to create something like this **`using divs`** and it also should be without using `display:table` css rule etc. How do I create table header this??

[image: Table Header]

Comment: you can use nested table for this case.

Comment: He specifically says `using divs`. @kumar...

Comment: hmmm yea got it thanks @praveen

Comment: i have post answer now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May be try this as a starting point? You might need to tweak it a lot.

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
.row {overflow: hidden; clear: both;}
.cell {border: 1px solid #999; padding: 0px; float: left;}
.cell.full {float: none;}
.col-1 {width: 20%;}
.col-2 {width: 40%;}
.col-3 {width: 60%;}
.col-33 {width: 33.3%;}
.row-2 {height: 3em;}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="cell col-1 row-2">Subject</div>
  <div class="cell col-3 row-2">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell full">First Term</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell col-33">October Test</div>
      <div class="cell col-33">December Exam</div>
      <div class="cell col-33">Term Average</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-1 row-2 cell">Teacher's Evaluation</div>
</div>
```

**Preview:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `flexbox` [can i use flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

The benefit of using `flexbox` is that you can get the the same result as you using the `table` tag including `vertical-align:middle`.

In the snippet, keep attention to the text-alignment in the cells.

You can use [flexboxgrid](http://flexboxgrid.com/) like this:

```css
[class*="col"] {
  text-align:center;
  border:1px solid;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/flexboxgrid/6.3.0/flexboxgrid.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row ">
  <div class="col-xs-3">Subject</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">First Term</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4">October Test</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">December Exam</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">Term Average</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">Teacher's Evaluation</div>
</div>
```

The result:

[image: screen shot]

http://jsbin.com/zetaro/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score -1):

Just use colspan and rowspan =)
[tutorial how to do it](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_table_span)

I made it:

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="2"><br>Subject<br></th>
    <th colspan="3">First term</th>
    <th rowspan="2">Teacher's Evaluation</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>October test</td>
    <td>December exam</td>
    <td>Term Average</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b3aqLny1/

Comment: And w3schools? Seriously?

Comment: Why have you written this answer?

Comment: Why have you written this answer? The fiddle contains `<table>`. What is asked is `<div>`.

Comment: It is obvious and easy to use tables.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```css
.table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  display: table;
  text-align: center;
}

.table .row{
  display: table-row;
}

.table .row .col {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  width: 33%;
}

.table .col.col-big {
  width: 50%;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}

.inner-table.table .row .col {border-width: 1px;}
```

```html
<div class="table">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col">
   <span>Subject</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col col-big">
   <div class="table inner-table">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col one-col" style="width: 100%">
      <span>First Term</span>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
     <div class="table inner-table">
       <div class="row">
         <div class="col"><span>Test 1</span></div>
              <div class="col"><span>Test 2</span></div>
              <div class="col"><span>Test 3</span></div>
       </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
   <span>Teacher's Evaluation</span>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `it also should be without using display:table`